# Dynamic Linking in C (lib*.so) library

Tags: c, unix, linker, posix, dynamic-linking

**I have written a code where in it would take in a *executable file* and the [lib*.so] library as my arguments and link @ Run-time.**

I want to also take in the **function in the (*.o) file @ run-time and link it**.
But I don't know how to go about it.

**EDIT 1:**
The function I'm trying to link is a part of the .o file in the lib*.so library.
*So I want to specify the library name and also the function name which is in the same library @ Run-Time.*

For eg. If my library contains two functions(i.e *.o files) the linker should compile the function which I want to use @Run-Time.

I have posted the code,please help :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>    // use -ldl

typedef float (*DepFn)(short, short);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* lib;
    DepFn df;

    if(argc < 2)
        return printf("USAGE: %s lib-file\n", argv[0]);

    lib = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
    if(lib == NULL)
        return printf("ERROR: Cannot load library\n");

    df = dlsym(lib, "Depreciation");
    if(df)
    {
        short l, i;

        printf("Enter useful-life of asset: ");
        scanf("%hd", &l);

        for(i = 1; i <= l; i++)
        {
            float d = 100 * df(l, i);
            printf("%hd\t%.1f%%\n", i, d);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("ERROR: Invalid library\n");

    dlclose(lib);
}
```

Comment: The code looks pretty ok, so what is actually happening ? What's not working ? And how did you compile and link your libXXX.so ?

Comment: @nos -- this is working fine.But I wanted to know how to also take in a function @ compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to take the function name at runtime, you need to pass it in argv[2], and instead of hardcoding function-name in the `dlsym` use argv[2].

```
if(argc < 3)
        return printf("USAGE: %s lib-file function-name\n", argv[0]);

    lib = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
    if(lib == NULL)
        return printf("ERROR: Cannot load library\n");

    df = dlsym(lib, argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load a relocatable (`*.o`) at run time using standard functions. You need to make sure the object is compiled as position independent code (e.g. `-fPIC`) and then make a shared object out of it. Something like `ld -shared -o foo.so foo.o` may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you just want to link to your shared library,

change your code to:

```
extern float Depreciation(short i,k); //should rather go in a header file

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    short l, i;

        printf("Enter useful-life of asset: ");
        scanf("%hd", &l);

        for(i = 1; i <= l; i++)
        {
            float d = 100 * Depreciation(l, i);
            printf("%hd\t%.1f%%\n", i, d);
        }
    }
```

Compile and link to your shared library:

```
 gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -lXX
```

Your libXX.so would need to be installed in e.g. /usr/lib/ for the above to work
See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) for more info.